# AsyncInvoker not releasing the Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using `AsyncInvoker` using Jersey 2.0. This works fine for me. However, thread is not ending after completion of the return. Please note that I don't expect any response for the services I call.

```
public Future<Response> fire(WebTarget webTarget) {
    Future<Response> response = null;

    try {
        response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                             .headers(headers)
                             .async().get();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return response;
}
```

Comment: any solution techies!!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't do anything with the actual `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` that is provided to you once the future value resolves, the request response stream is kept open (and the thread associated with it the raw HTTP request as wel I guess). You should either:

1. Do something with the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object and close it (or it's stream).
2. Use [.get(MyPojo.class)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/AsyncInvoker.html#get-java.lang.Class-) to have the response steam converted into an actual object. This will close the stream for you and resolve a `MyPojo` instance in the future instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `client` object that you created in the calling method. In the calling method you would have something like below -

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

WebTarget webTarget = client.target(SERVER_URL).path(API_PATH).path(String.valueOf(id));

fire(webTarget);
```

So you need to close your `client` after calling this method -

```
client.close()
```

However, the recommended way of closing `client` is after receiving response. Something like below -

```
public void fire(WebTarget webTarget) {

    try {
        webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                             .headers(headers)
                             .async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {

          @Override
          public void completed(Response response) {
              // Do whatever your wish with response
              client.close();
          }

          @Override
          public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
              throwable.printStackTrace();
              client.close();
          }
      });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```